# Store streaming data - fast, cheap, reliable and good for batch consumption

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, storage

I have a (spring-boot) web service that generates a json response for each request. This response, while returned to the querying user, also needs to be archived somewhere (so that we know what we responded with to the user).

The service needs to support 4,000 requests/second. As such, we need the archival method to be fast. The archived data would later be consumed by a map-reduce (batch) job.

I want to know which solution to use - Kafka, S3, or any other solution. The service has been deployed to AWS. So solutions within AWS are ideal.

The requirements are as follows:

- Writes should be fast 94K req/s at least).
- Writes should be non-blocking (so that the service response time is not affected).
- Reads need not be fast but should be suitable for consumption by map-reduce jobs.
- Data should be resilient to server crashes etc.
- Should not be too expensive to write/store and read.

There is no `data retirement plan`, i.e. the data needs to persist until the end of time.

Which solutions do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your requirements like "should not be too expensive" are a bit vague. In the end, you are going to need to evaluate a service against all of your exact requirements yourself.

Given that qualification, I would look into streaming the data to Kenesis with the goal of archiving the data to S3. I recommend reading [this blog post](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2MUQB5PRWU36K/Persist-Streaming-Data-to-Amazon-S3-using-Amazon-Kinesis-Firehose-and-AWS-Lambda) from AWS to get an idea of how to achieve this.